# RTMP поток

Tags: веб-программирование, сервер, видео

В общем, есть такой вопрос. Есть RTMP поток, который можно смотреть, только имея российский айпи, есть ли возможность сделать, к примеру, такое: арендовать сервер (какой не знаю), установить ПО (не знаю какое), чтобы происходило конвертирование потока в mp4 или flv, создавая файл. Ну, уж потом брать ссылку на файл и транслировать ее у себя. Ну что-то в этом роде или можно как-то еще  добиться, чтобы люди с других стран могли смотреть данный RTMP поток.

Answer (score 1):

Арендуйте любой VPS сервер, поставьте на нём erlyvideo в качестве ретранслятора и раздавайте это видео.